# SQL Server confuses month and day of datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, format, date-formatting

When I have to debug Stored Procedures I often trace the exact RPC call that is made with the SQL Profiler. I then look at the variable declarations that were used when to call the Stored Procedure and use these declarations to debug the procedure.

If one parameter is of datatype `datetime` I declare the variable as follows:

```
DECLARE @MyDate datetime = '2017-05-12 00:00:00'
```

Note that this is also the format the SQL Profiler uses to show the call.

When I then print `@MyDate`, it is not the *12th of May* which I would expect. Instead, SQL Server interprets it as the *5th of December*.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
PRINT @MyDate
```

yields

```
Dec  5 2017 12:00AM
```

How can I achieve the expected result, that is, that `PRINT @MyDate` yields `May 12 2017 12:00AM`.

**UPDATE:**

As requested in the comments, I show which part I am pulling from the SQL Profiler. The profiler shows this call:

```
exec NAME_OF_STORED_PROCEDURE @MyDate'2017-05-12 00:00:00'
```

I then use the `@MyDate'2017-05-12 00:00:00'` and change it to `DECLARE @MyDate = '2017-05-12 00:00:00'`

Comment: Use a non-ambiguos format for your date (yyyymmdd): `DECLARE @MyDate datetime = '20170512'`

Comment: my issue is that I copy/paste from the SQL profiler. I would expect this to be the correct format. I don't want to modify the declaration as it is shown by the SQL profiler.

Comment: well, if you don't want to modify the statement, then I guess you'll have to deal with getting ambiguous results

Comment: the meta-question is: why does the SQL Profile provide a variable declaration statement that is wrong when it is used directly?

Comment: Please post which part you're pulling from the profiler, and which part you're adding yourself in order to query it.

Comment: What is your systems default language set as? I am in the UK, so if I tried to print a date of 2017-30-05 I get the error of a date time out of range, and if I try as you have above, I get the 12th May, as the British date format would expect.

Comment: @Eli I updated the OP according to your request

Comment: @Leonidas199x good point. the main reason why this confuses me is, that I am 100% sure that it has worked the way I previously expected it to.

Comment: How is the proc being called? Is it though an application?

Comment: @beta when I read your question, it got me thinking, how does SQL determine how to format a date, if you don't give it anything other than the date itself, and it does go off the date settings within the region and language config. Be interesting to know if that is set in the format you expect the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters passed via an RPC call are sent to SQL Server in native (binary) format. The text you see in a Profiler (or Extended Events visualization) is just a reverse-engineered rendering of the native values passed via the TDS protocol. Unfortunately, the string format displayed is not a neutral ISO date so you need to tweak the format manually if you copy/paste the text.

I filed this [feedback suggestion on connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/302236/use-neutral-date-format-for-datetime-parameter-values) 10 years ago to use a neutral date format. Please upvote.

Comment: Good explanation. thanks. btw I have to use `SET DATEFORMAT ymd` in my case, and then it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dashes, as you will thereby remove ambiguity in date format:

```
DECLARE @MyDate datetime = '20170512 00:00:00'

SET DATEFORMAT DMY
PRINT @MyDate
```

Yields: `May 12 2017 12:00AM`

Answer (score 0):

I have to use `SET DATEFORMAT ymd` in my case, and then it works as expected